# How do I get a Loader to no longer fill its parent?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I have a Loader object in my main QML file. I load different QML sources in the loader at run time depending on the current context.

My steps are like this:

1. Load a `login.qml` file and set `anchors.centerIn: parent` on the Loader.
2. After successfully logging in, I load `task.qml` and then set `anchors.fill: parent` on the Loader.
3. After the user logs out, I want to redirect back to `login.qml`, and I set `anchors.centerIn: parent` again on the loader.

I would expect this would cause the Loader to be centered in the parent and no longer fill it. However, this is not the case. The Loader still fills the parent.

**How do I change the anchors on an Item so it is centered again and no longer fills its parent?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to set `anchors.centerIn` again. Instead, you need to set `anchors.fill` and `width` and `height` to `undefined` so it defaults to the implicit size and again uses the `anchors.centerIn` property.

Here's a working example:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0

Item {
    width: 800
    height: 600

    Rectangle {
        id: rect
        anchors.centerIn: parent

        implicitWidth: 500
        implicitHeight: 200
        color: "red"

        Button {
            text: "Toggle Full Size"
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            onClicked: {
                if (rect.anchors.fill) {
                    rect.anchors.fill = undefined
                    rect.width = undefined
                    rect.height = undefined
                } else {
                    rect.anchors.fill = rect.parent
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, a simpler solution might be to make your Loader always fill its parent and instead add an extra Item at the top level of your `login.qml` file so the login view is centered in this Item. That would remove the necessity to change the anchor on the Loader.